# Apcu is not enabled when installed with apt-get on PHP7.2-apache stretch image

Tags: apcu, php-7.2

I installed php-apcu with apt-get install on PHP7.2-apache-stretch but not able to enable it. The apcu.so and apcu.ini files are created during installation .  Service Apache is also restarted and the content of apcu.ini is also good but php -m is not showing apcu in the list. Had also tried phpenmod but still it doesn't seem to work. However I am not getting any error during installation .  The problem seems to be related to image because i had also tried to install apcu in the same way on fresh Debian image and it's working.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 9):

Install PHP7.2-dev via `apt install PHP7.2-dev` and thereafter run `pecl install apcu` and add the extension to the php.ini.

Answer (score 7):

Just posting an answer here in case someone else has the same problem I did trying to execute PHPUnit tests...

I was trying to run some automated feature tests that use APCu and could not for the life of me figure out why `apcu_enabled()` was always returning `false` on my local machine. I had installed everything correctly via `pecl install apcu` and added the `extension=apcu.so` entry to my `php.ini` file, etc. `phpinfo` also showed the extension was enabled properly.

Turns out that I needed to add `apc.enable_cli=1` to my `php.ini` file so that APCu would work with CLI commands. I hope this saves you the 5 days of your life that I will never get back.

Comment: after spending 30 minutes debugging on this, i found this answer and totally make the day (maybe even five of them)
Thank you a lot

Comment: Prob a typo but it should be `apc.enable_cli=1` not `api....`

Comment: @RcoderNY I faced the same. Had to look for it. Updated. Reference: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/caching_configuration.html#id1

Comment: In CLI, this can be set using the parameter `-d apc.enable_cli=1`